# Android Studio and proguard configuration

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

I am using Android Studio 0.2.6 on Windows 7 x32.

Does anybody have a clue on how to set up gradle and pro-guard so it actually obfuscates and compresses the java classes

During the "Generate Signed APK Wizard", there is a checkbox to "Run Proguard" along with a "Config File Path:" and "Include system proguard file" checkbox.

But who knows how to configure the proguard-project-.txt file to actually do the work instead of packaging the classes without compression or obfuscation so that the APK decompiler can easily recover the class code.

Anybody know which forum or which URL location for ProGuard user expertise related To Android Studio?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html